# Error when using iText: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, pdf, webforms, itext

This error comes when I do not close the previously opened PDF file and create a new PDF again. I want to open the second file without closing the first file.

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\Slip.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

```
try
{
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(190f, 240f), 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

    PdfWriter pdfwriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/Slip.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    pdfDoc.Open();

    PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(2);
    table1.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
    table1.SetWidths(new int[] { 1, 6 });

    string imagepath = Server.MapPath("Images");
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/sliplogo.png");
    image.ScalePercent(24f);
    table1.AddCell(image);

    //   Text.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Text1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    Text.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    table1.AddCell(Text1);
    table1.AddCell("");
    table1.AddCell(Text);
    //  table1.AddCell(phrase);

    PdfPTable orderInfoTable5 = new PdfPTable(1);
    orderInfoTable5.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
    orderInfoTable5.AddCell("-------------------------------------");

    string tme = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
    Paragraph Text2 = new Paragraph(tme, new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.NORMAL));

    Paragraph Text3 = new Paragraph(DateAssign, new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8, Font.NORMAL));

    pdfDoc.Add(table1);
    Text2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    pdfDoc.Add(Text2);

    Text3.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    pdfDoc.Add(orderInfoTable5);

    pdfDoc.Close();
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/Slip.pdf");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: if they have the same exact path you cannot do that.  perhaps make a copy to work with then copy back?  or just work in RAM in the c# program.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Check the code. I have edited the post.

Comment: Formatting your code properly and removing unnecessary white space makes it easier to read and easier for people to help you.

Comment: I need a solid solution. Can you help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated NOTE** on this solution: Checking with FileAccess.ReadWrite will fail for Read-Only files so the solution has been modified to check with FileAccess.Read. While this solution works because trying to check with FileAccess.Read will fail if the file has a Write or Read lock on it, however, this solution will not work if the file doesn't have a Write or Read lock on it, i.e. it has been opened (for reading or writing) with FileShare.Read or FileShare.Write access.

**ORIGINAL**: I've used this code for the past several years, and I haven't had any issues with it.

Understand your hesitation about using exceptions, but you can't avoid them all of the time

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        //the file is unavailable because it is:
        //still being written to
        //or being processed by another thread
        //or does not exist (has already been processed)
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this code will only work when the file is previously created. Because you have changed it to FileMode.Open. So it will throw an exception on creating the pdf file even on first time.

Comment: Please check the code which I have given on the post.

Comment: If file is used by someone that means its previously created. @Sufyan161

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that if you want to keep the file open.

You may try closing the file, overwrite it and reopen the file again in minimized mode

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I don't want to close the file. That's not programmatic approach. And if I close the file, then create it then it opens. My issue is that if the user forgets to close the pdf file and clicks the button to create a new file again then it gives an error.

Comment: Please check the code which I have given on the post.